# How property actually manages to return Priority?

Tags: c#, properties, queue

Here is the piece of code which represents so-called wrapper class PriorityQueue which contains three ordinary queues of different priority (High, Medium and Low) and tied with Enumeration Priority to which class Package () is connected via it's read-only property by the name Priority. And the Priority is being assigned via CreatePackage() method of PackageFactory class which creates objects (instances) of class Package (Package class have a constructor which requires to point it's _priority member in parentheses) using Random class and cast from int to Priority. This is the general background. Code is following below:

```
namespace PriorityQueue
```

{
enum Priority
{
High,
Medium,
Low
}

```
interface IPrioritizable
{
    Priority Priority { get; }
}

class PriorityQueue<T> where T:IPrioritizable
{
    private Queue<T> _queueHigh = new Queue<T>();
    private Queue<T> _queueMedium = new Queue<T>();
    private Queue<T> _queueLow = new Queue<T>();
    
    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        switch (item.Priority)
        {
            case PriorityQueue.Priority.High:
                _queueHigh.Enqueue(item);
                break;
            case PriorityQueue.Priority.Medium:
                _queueMedium.Enqueue(item);
                break;
            case PriorityQueue.Priority.Low:
                _queueLow.Enqueue(item);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(item.Priority.ToString(), "Bad priority in Priority queue. ");
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        Queue<T> queueTop = TopQueue();
        if (queueTop != null & queueTop.Count > 0)
        { 
            return queueTop.Dequeue();
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    private Queue<T> TopQueue()
    {
        if (_queueHigh != null & _queueHigh.Count > 0) return _queueHigh;
        if (_queueMedium != null & _queueMedium.Count > 0) return _queueMedium;
        if (_queueLow != null & _queueLow.Count > 0) return _queueLow;
        return _queueLow;
    }

    public int Count ()
    {
        return _queueHigh.Count + _queueMedium.Count + _queueLow.Count;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return (_queueHigh.Count == 0) & (_queueMedium.Count == 0) & (_queueLow.Count == 0);
    }
}

class Package:IPrioritizable
{
    private Priority _priority;

    public Package(Priority priority)
    {
        _priority = priority;
    }

    public Priority Priority => _priority;
}

class PackageFactory
{
    Random _randgen = new Random();
    public Package CreatePackage()
    {
        int numOfPriority = _randgen.Next(3);
        return new Package((Priority)numOfPriority);
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating PriorityQueue...");
        PriorityQueue<Package> pq = new PriorityQueue<Package>();
        Package pack;
        PackageFactory fact = new PackageFactory();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("\nNow we are going to create random number of 0-20 range as a number of packets to be created. ");
        int numsToCreate = rnd.Next(20);
        Console.WriteLine("\nAnd now we are creating {0} packages: ", numsToCreate);
        for (int i = 0; i < numsToCreate; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\tPackage {0} ", i);
            pack = fact.CreatePackage();
            Console.WriteLine("priority is: {0} ", pack.Priority);
            pq.Enqueue(pack);
        }
        int total = pq.Count();
        Console.WriteLine("\nTotal number of packages received is: {0}", total);

        Console.WriteLine("\nNow we are going to create random number of 0-20 range as a number of packets to be removed. ");
        int numsToRemove = rnd.Next(20);
        Console.WriteLine("\nAnd now we are removing up to {0} packages: ", numsToRemove);
        for (int i = 0; i < numsToRemove; i++)
        {
            pack = pq.Dequeue();
            if(pack != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Removed (shipped) package with priority: {0} ", pack.Priority);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of packages removed (shipped) is: {0}", total - pq.Count());

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to terminate program...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Also there are customised Enqueue() and Dequeue() methods for PriorityQueue class. Actually what I don't understand is the Main() part of the program where we are using customised Dequeue() method to remove instances of Package class. How does the program learns of removed package via Priority property after customised Dequeue() method being used? Object was removed and how it can learn it Priority? Does it have to do something with reference types? Here is the part which I question:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numsToRemove; i++)
        {
            pack = pq.Dequeue();
            if(pack != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Removed (shipped) package with priority: {0} ", pack.Priority);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Package` implements `IPrioritizable` => it has a `Priority` property. The value is given to it during its construction (`CreatePackage` in `PackageFactory`). It will not lose that value during its lifetime (unless explicitly forced to, but that does not apply here).

Comment: But isn't instance of the Package class goes to nowhere and cease to exist after Dequeue() method was used? Then if it ceased to exist then how Priority property actually get priority of deleted (or removed) instance of the Package class?

Comment: _"But isn't instance of the Package class goes to nowhere and cease to exist after Dequeue() method was used?"_ - No. Why do you think that? You are still holding on to a reference to the object in the variable `pack`. Only when you reassign to that or it goes out of scope, no more references are kept anywhere and it will be eligible for Garbage Collection.

Comment: Maybe the `if(pack != null)`check is confusing you? (Which actually should be `if( pack is not null )` in recent versions of C#/.NET) - But that's only for the case, where you have more "count" to dequeue than have been enqueued. In that case, Dequeue returns `default` which is `null` in this case.

Comment: Thank you Fildor! I think that you explained what I just suspected regards to reference types. Don’t know why it’s not that easy to get get a grasp on this border between value and reference types. It’s just difficult for me to imagine how reference types are stored and handled.

Comment: It will get easier as you progress :D